# Arguments to exe in properties right click windows 10

Tags: windows-10

If I recall correctly you could add command line arguments in the properties dialog when right clicking an .exe end. In the dialog there were some field where you can add arguments so that they are always executed when running the .exe?

Has that been removed/moved in win 10 or some update or am i looking in the wrong place?

Picture only for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you're not confusing it with a Shortcut?

This from a fairly random app in Windows 7. Note the shortcut has a command-line type property usually used to add launch arguments. The app itself doesn't.

[image]

Comment: I am sure I was confusing it with that, makes total sense, thanks!